# Wordpress search with meta_query leads to 404

Tags: php, wordpress, search

I'm a little rusty with Wordpress (it's been a minute) but I'm having an issue with setting up a search page for a custom post type (lp-cat). Actually two issues:

1. The regular search (see code below) works fine, but the meta_query isn't going through, i.e. returning no results, even when I know it should if it worked properly
2. After editing the query_vars in function.php to match the keys in the meta_query (which I thought was the problem and maybe it is), the ensuing URL with the GETs in it for the search returns a 404 page

I'm not sure why, in either case. Possibly the combination of an 's' search and the meta_query is causing the issue? Not getting errors (except the 404), just not returning any results from the title, author, and subtitle fields. Code for the page and functions.php included below. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

page template:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$search_string = get_query_var('book-search');
$author = get_query_var('author');
$title = get_query_var('title');
$subtitle = get_query_var('subtitle');

global $post;

get_header();
?>

<form method="GET" action="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>">
    <ul class="book-search-form">
        <li>
            <label for="book-search"><?php _e('Search...', 'txtdomain'); ?></label>
            <input type="text" id="book-search" name="book-search" value="<?php echo $search_string; ?>" />
        </li>       
        <li>
            <label for="title"><?php _e('title', 'txtdomain'); ?></label>
            <input type="text" id="title" name="title" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="author"><?php _e('author', 'txtdomain'); ?></label>
            <input type="text" id="author" name="author" value="<?php echo $author; ?>" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="subtitle"><?php _e('subtitle', 'txtdomain'); ?></label>
            <input type="text" id="subtitle" name="subtitle" value="<?php echo $subtitle; ?>" />
        </li>
    </ul>
    <input type="submit" value="<?php _e('Search', 'txtdomain'); ?>" />
</form>

<?php
    $tmp_wpquery = $wp_query;
    $wp_query = null;
?>

<table id="catalog-table">
    <tr>
        <td>MEDIA ID</td>
        <td>TITLE ID</td>
        <td>TITLE</td>
        <td>SUBTITLE</td>
        <td>AUTHOR</td>
        <td>NARRATOR</td>
    </tr>

<?php
$args = [
    'post_type' => 'lp-cat',
    'posts_per_page' => 20,
    'orderby' => 'titleid',
    'paged' => $paged
];

$meta_query = [];

if (!empty($search_string)) {
    $args['s'] = $search_string;
}

if (!empty($author)) {
    $meta_query[] = [
        'key' => 'author',
        'value' => $author,
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    ];
}

if (!empty($title)) {
    $meta_query[] = [
        'key' => 'title',
        'value' => $title,
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    ];
}

if (!empty($subtitle)) {
    $meta_query[] = [
        'key' => 'subtitle',
        'value' => $subtitle,
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    ];
}

if (!empty($meta_query)) {
    $args['meta_query'] = $meta_query;
}

$books = new WP_Query($args);
$wp_query = $books;

if (have_posts()) {
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        $post_id = get_the_ID();
        $fields = get_post_custom($post_id);
        //var_dump($fields);
        ?><tr>
            <td><?php echo $fields["mediaid"][0]?></td>
            <td><?php echo $fields["titleid"][0]?></td>
            <td><?php echo $fields["title"][0]?></td>
            <td><?php echo $fields["subtitle"][0]?></td>
            <td><?php echo $fields["author"][0]?></td>
            <td><?php echo $fields["narrator"][0]?></td>
        </tr><?php
    //echo $GLOBALS['wp_query']->request;
    endwhile;
    
    the_posts_pagination([
        "mid_size" => 2,
        "prev_text" => __("Previous", "txtdomain"),
        "next_text" => __("Next", "txtdomain")
    ]);
} else {
    ?>"<p class='body-text'><?php _e("No books found", "txtdomain"); ?></p><?php
}

$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = $tmp_wpquery;
?>
```

functions.php (the relevant part):

```
add_filter('query_vars', function($vars) {
    $vars[] = 'book-search';
    $vars[] = 'author';
    $vars[] = 'title';
    $vars[] = 'subtitle';
    return $vars;
});
```